# Undefined not a function issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have a Backbone.js application that has a js file that looks like:

```
var ProductView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render','createProduct');

        this.render();
    },

    events: {
        "click #createProduct": "createProduct"
    },

    render: function() {
        var source = $('#product-template').html();
        var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
        var html = template(this.model.toJSON());
        this.$el.html(html);
    },


    createProduct: function(){
        var product_title = this.$(".title").val();
        var product_description = this.$(".description").val();

        var data = [];

        $(".product").each( function(){
            var type = $( this ).data("type");

            var wd = new Object();

            if (this.$(".adInput").val())           { wd.ad      = this.$(".adInput").val();            }
            if (this.$(".citeInput").val())             { wd.cite        = this.$(".citeInput").val();          }
            if (this.$(".addressInput").val())      { wd.address     = this.$(".addressInput").val();       }

            alert(wd);
        });

    }
```

I'm getting the error:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function main.js?body=1:61
 (anonymous function) main.js?body=1:61
 jQuery.extend.each jquery.js?body=1:385
 jQuery.fn.jQuery.each jquery.js?body=1:138
 Backbone.View.extend.createProduct main.js?body=1:56
 jQuery.event.dispatch jquery.js?body=1:4625
 elemData.handle
```

Also, my html looks like:

```
<div class='item ad' data-type="ad">
  <textarea class='adInput' placeholder='Ad'></textarea>
  <input class='citeInput' type='text'/>
</div>
```

Thanks for all help!

Comment: What line does it refer to?

Comment: `if (this.$(".adInput").val()){ wd.ad = this.$(".adInput").val();  }`

Comment: But if I take that line out, the error transfers to the next line?

Comment: `console.log(this.$, this)` in both places where it works and where it doesn't and see the difference.

Comment: If I take the code out of the each block, it doesn't throw an error anymore.

Comment: Of course it doesn't - it's (the `$.each()` block) not coded well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is in this statement :

```
if (this.$(".adInput").val())
    wd.ad = this.$(".adInput").val();
```

Try replacing it with :

```
if ($(this).find(".adInput").val())
    wd.ad = $(this).find(".adInput").val();
```

this.$(selector) is a Backbone method defined in a View. You can see it [here](http://backbonejs.org/#View-dollar).

In the anonymous function invoked by each iterator, the context of `this` gets changed. It no more refers to the View. You can use $(this) to get the element being currently processed by the each iterator and use find on it to select elements which belong to it's hierarchy. This is exactly what Backbone's view $ method does.

```
$: function(selector) {
   return this.$el.find(selector);
}
```

Similarly correct the other 2 if blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Change  this

```
 var wd = new Object();
```

to this

```
var wd = {ad: '', cite: '', address: ''};
```

And (".addressInput") is invalid because i cant find any DOM element in your HTML with this class

Comment: why? Isn't that just declaring an object a different way?